# Is it correct to say l enjoy seeing places?

Tags: sentence-construction

How to use the present participle of the verb to see. Can I say, "I enjoy seeing new places"?

Comment: Yes, You're correct. If someone enjoy doing something, they get pleasure from that thing. (In your sentence the subject gets pleasure from seeing(visiting)new places ).

Comment: Note that ***enjoy*** can only be followed by a ***noun*** (such as *I enjoy **movies***, or a "gerund verb-as-noun" such as *I enjoy **watching** movies*). That's not the same as ***like***, which can take infinitives as well as nouns: *I like **to watch** movies.* It's also not the same as ***want***, which can take ordinary nouns *(I want **food**, I want **a cigarette**),* and infinitives *(I want **to go**),* but not gerunds (*I want watching movies* is invalid).

Answer (score 1):

As @Sam has commented,

> I enjoy seeing new places.

is fine.

*seeing* is called a gerund-participle in modern grammar.  In traditional grammar, it was a gerund in this context.